# Is there a way to run some code before parallel tests begin?

Tags: java, cucumber-java

I'm using cucumber-jvm-parellel-plugin. The feature files are run in parallel. But I would like to execute some code before the tests begin i.e. in a way that the code will only be executed once, rather than within each parallel runner.

Comment: If u r using maven then use the exec-maven-plugin to execute the single time run code. Set it to execute in a suitable phase before the tests are executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, please add annotations @BeforeClass from JUnit/TestNG and Similarly you can use @AfterClass in your run cuke class. This piece of code would run once before running your first class and after all test execution completed.